# Multiple joins subquery SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]

On the left you'll see my design for one table, on the right you'll see the results from the subquery in the SQL below.  I'm trying to join the subquery on the three fields `patientID,claimsFromDate,claimsThroughDate` on tblClaims, and have the outer query associate the correct `tblClaims.ID` with the three part join.

The errors I'm getting:

> line 3, incorrect syntax near the keyword select`and`incorrect
>   syntax near the ), line 12

```
select tblClaims.id, t.primaryCode
from t
(
select patientid, claimsfromdate, claimsthroughDate, primarycode from myTable
union
select patientid, claimsfromDate, claimsthroughDate, secondaryCode from myTable
union
select patientID, claimsfromdate, claimsthroughDate, tertiarycode from myTable

) as t
inner join t on tblclaims.patientid=t.patientid 
and tblclaims.claimsfromdate=t.claimsfromdate
and tblclaims.cllaimsthroughdate=t.claimsfromdate
```

EDIT: The inner query is to reconcile a multi column field.  It returns 1.5 million rows.
the fixed query I ran returned 3.5 million which was

`select tblClaims.id, t.primarycode 
from 
(
select patientid, claimsfromdate, claimsthroughDate, primarycode from myTable
) as t
inner join tblclaims on tblclaims.patientid=t.patientid 
and tblclaims.claimsfromdate=t.claimsfromdate
and tblclaims.cllaimsthroughdate=t.claimsfromdate`

Comment: No wonder you didn't see it - there is t after from, just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select tblClaims.id, t.primarycode 
from 
(
select patientid, claimsfromdate, claimsthroughDate, primarycode from myTable
) as t
inner join tblclaims on tblclaims.patientid=t.patientid 
and tblclaims.claimsfromdate=t.claimsfromdate
and tblclaims.cllaimsthroughdate=t.claimsfromdate
```

Comment: This runs, but it returns about three times too many rows, I don't think it will make a difference but I'll edit the query to include the entire query (I wanted to save on clutter).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `Distinct` ?

```
select DISTINCT tblClaims.id, t.primarycode 
from 
(
    select patientid, claimsfromdate, claimsthroughDate, primarycode from myTable
) as t
inner join tblclaims on tblclaims.patientid=t.patientid 
and tblclaims.claimsfromdate=t.claimsfromdate
and tblclaims.cllaimsthroughdate=t.claimsfromdate
```